# spring boot gradle plugin change project dependencies version

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I ran into a problem that puzzled me.
I use gradle build spring-boot project and i want package a runtime jar.

this is my dependencies :

```
buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.5.RELEASE")
        }
}

plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.5.RELEASE'
    }
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.0.0'
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.0.0'
    ....
}
```

i run the cmd `gradle dependencies` :

```
+--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.0.0 -> 2.4.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.4
|    |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.5.4
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.4
|    |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.5.4
```

when i remove spring-boot plugin, Everything is normal.

i change spring-boot plugin version. some time There are some dependencies Will change the version.

please help me check it question, thx !